# flyway executes "alter table ... modify `col` auto_increment" on MySQL but doesn't change `col` values

Tags: mysql, sql, flyway

When I execute these sentences from MySQL command line or Workbench...

```
-- 1) Add a column `id`
ALTER TABLE `DEVICES` ADD `id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL;
-- 2) Add an index, necessary for auto_increment
ALTER TABLE `DEVICES` ADD index `devices_id_index`(`id`);
-- 3) Makes `id` auto_increment and inserts sequential numbers it (from 1 to N)
ALTER TABLE `DEVICES` MODIFY `id` BIGINT(20) AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

... what I get is a new column `id` that is filled with auto-increment values from 1 to N.

But when I execute it from **flyway**, the column `id` has a zero in every row because the last sentence doesn't change its values.

Do you know why?

Any solution/workaround besides inserting those values using a procedure?

Thank you!

Ferran

Comment: You do? I would have expected the first statement to error.

Comment: Why would you expect it to error, Tony?

Comment: Can't add a not null column to a table, because you don't have a value to put in the column. Daresay whatever tool you are using is being a bit clever, possibly too clever. Or maybe it's another piece on non-standardness in Mysql.

Comment: I think that code works even in the MySQL command line. I don't know what does flyway do to fail.